# python: ограничить размер целых чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа, int

В питоне целые числа имеют неограниченный размер (ограничено лишь памятью)

А можно ли ограничить размер целых чисел, чтобы скажем `100**100` или `math.factorial(100)` уже не вычислялось, а выпадало бы исключение?

Comment: Не знаю такого способа. Вам придется вручную следить за аргументами всех операций. * Как мне кажется *100**100* совсем не большое число.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать декоратор:

```
def big_number_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(n):
        if n > 100:
            raise ValueError(f"Число {n} превышает максимальное значение!")
        return func(n)
    return wrapper

@big_number_decorator
def big_number(n):
    return n

try:
    big_number(100)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Теперь при вызове функции, сперва отработает декоратор, проверит что число не больше нужного и только потом вызовет вашу функцию или выбьет исключение и вычисление не произойдёт.

Comment: недостаток этого метода - надо самому следить за всеми арифметическими операциями
а идеально было бы установить питону како-ли лимит и дальше пусть у него у самого голова болит